# SQL : IF ELSE with THEN of SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am sorry if this duplicate question. Please let me know where I can find right question. I have a stored procedure where I can just make few minor modifications and I cannot change/update data in my Student table. We have this problem and I need to fix it.

In below statement, sometimes student.FullName will have [NEXTLINE] in it then I need to replace it with '' ( empty string) else nothing return as it is. I tried various ways but getting error when I replace +student.FullName in THEN clause. Please let me know how can I do this.

```
CASE
 WHEN student.ID IS NULL THEN 
 CASE 
    WHEN student.Status = 0 THEN '<BOLDSTART>rejected<BOLDEND>.'+'[LINEBREAK]'+ student.FullName                                    
    WHEN student.Status = 1 THEN ' <BOLDSTART>accepted<BOLDEND>.'
 END
END
```

I want to add similar logic like below in above +student.FullName

```
IF (student.FullName LIKE '%[NEXTLINE]%')
BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE (student.FullName,'[NEXTLINE]','')
END
ELSE
SELECT student.FullName
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Thanks to D Stanley. I solved my problem like below

```
CASE
 WHEN student.ID IS NULL THEN 
    WHEN student.Status = 0 THEN '<BOLDSTART>rejected<BOLDEND>.' + '[LINEBREAK]' + REPLACE (student.FullName,'[NEXTLINE]','')
    WHEN student.Status = 1 THEN ' <BOLDSTART>accepted<BOLDEND>.'
END
```

Comment: @lad2025: Thanks for editing. I was about to do it..

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Ziggler Just update the question with propper tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to see if it contains the string.  If it does not, `REPLACE` will just return the original string:

```
CASE
 WHEN student.ID IS NULL THEN 
 CASE 
    WHEN student.Status = 0 THEN 
        '<BOLDSTART>rejected<BOLDEND>.'+'[LINEBREAK]'+ REPLACE(student.FullName,'[NEXTLINE]','')                                   
    WHEN student.Status = 1 THEN 
        ' <BOLDSTART>accepted<BOLDEND>.'
 END
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

replace

```
+ student.FullName
```

for

```
+ CASE 
     WHEN student.FullName LIKE '%[NEXTLINE]%' THEN REPLACE (student.FullName,'[NEXTLINE]','')
     ELSE student.FullName
  END
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. It helped me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap your entire logic in a `replace()` call:

```
REPLACE((CASE WHEN student.ID IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
              WHEN student.Status = 0
              THEN '<BOLDSTART>rejected<BOLDEND>.' + '[LINEBREAK]' + student.FullName                                    
              WHEN student.Status = 1
              THEN ' <BOLDSTART>accepted<BOLDEND>.'
         END), '[NEXTLINE]', ''
        )
```

Notice that I also simplified your logic.  The nested case statements are not necessary.  `case` is evaluated sequentially, so you can just check for the conditions you want.